# Want to submit and save form data using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I want to submit and save form data by using javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Save data using JS</title> 
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Sign up</h1>
<form name="myForm">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" required maxlength="40"><br><br>
 E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>
  Gender:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
   
</body>
</html>
```

So, when i click submit button, form data should be saved somewhere, for every user who fills and submits it. This should be done using Javascript,jquery or ajax.

Comment: So where did you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: As u can see above, i have just created a form, now i want when a user submits the form, form data should be saved somewhere.

Comment: @Manish, Then what is the question ? What is not working ?

Comment: I hope you are saving data in database as this is Sign Up form. Right?

Comment: I want data to be stored locally somewhere, want to just use javascript,jquery or ajax.

Comment: You can use localStorage. refer link [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Also, if i want to save form data in database , can it be done using javascript

Comment: @Manish In which database you want to save?

Comment: @Apb i want in mysql

Comment: @Manish JavaScript can not directly connect to MySQL. But you can mix JS with PHP to do so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107814/discussion-between-manish-and-apb).

Answer (score 3):

if you want to save it locally use cookies
the code bellow will save your answer to the person computer using cookies:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Save data using JS</title> 
</head>
<script>
 function saveData() {
  document.cookie="fname="+document.getElementById('fname').value+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC";
  document.cookie="email="+document.getElementById('email').value+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC";

  var radios = document.getElementsByName('gender');

  for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
        document.cookie="gender="+radios[i].value+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC";
        break;
    }
}
 alert('Data Saved!');
}
 alert('SAVED DATA: '+document.cookie);
</script>
<body>
  <h1>Sign up</h1>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="javascript:saveData();">
  Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" required maxlength="40"><br><br>
 E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required><br><br>
  Gender:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

if you want to save it on a database.
submit the form to a page that can run some back-end code, like php, asp, coldfision, jsp, or what ever you favorite language is.

***NOTE: a more modern way of storing data is using Window.localStorage.
      but its not compatible with older browsers.. but it does, have certain improvements over cookies, you don't have to reload the page to see the changes. data never expires. you can store larger amounts of data, then you can in cookies.***

Comment: data is saved in my browser??

Comment: yes, your browser keeps some storage space, where websites can save info locally.. so, the next time you return to that website, it can retrieve the local information. you can read the data back... using document.cookie

Comment: How can i view the data which is saved.

Comment: If person deletes the cookies ??

Comment: I modified the code above to display your saved data when you first open the page up.
if person deletes the cookie, then the data is gone... if you run the code above, at first you will see an alert screen. with the saved data. at first there is no data, fill in some data, submit the form. close the window an open it again, the next time the alert will display the data you saved form last time... and that is how you get your data back.

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way we can view the data, that was saved fair time ago?

Comment: the data can be very old you will still be able to see it, if you want the data to stay there forever, set the expiration year to something like 9999, if the person never clears his cookies, you can come back 50 years later and your data will still be there.... so, how old depends on your expiration date.

Comment: Yes, the data will be there. But we are seeing on browser the data saved last time. So, how can we view data saved suppose, 10 days ago ??

Comment: that data will stay there for as long as you want it, submit some data.. forget about the page.. come back 10 days from today, you will she that the data is still there.

Comment: Yes i got you. so, although data is there, but we can't see it. Is that right?

Comment: Actually anyone who has access to their computer can see the data if they know what they are doing.. after all its saved just as a plain text file, on the person computer.

Comment: @Manish stackover flow is saying this conversation is too long, if you have any more questions you can email me directly at sergio@dominicanvoice.com or start a chat here.. which I've never done since I'm new here. I'll answer any other questions you might have.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to use php and ajax then refer this link:

http://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

For this you must have a database in MY-SQL.

Comment: Any more reference, u can share

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(1*24*60*60*1000));
    createCookie('fname', $('input[name=fname]').val(), date);
    createCookie('email', $('input[name=fname]').val(), date);
    createCookie('gender', $('input:checked').val(), date);
});
```

Just realized I forgot the createCookie function...

```
function createCookie(name, value, date){
    var c = name + '=' + value + "; expires=" + date;
    document.cookie = c;
}
```

Comment: what is it doing??

Comment: Creates three cookies when user clicks submit button. First is value of fname field. Second is value of email field. Third is value of checked gender field (Male or Female). The cookie will expire in 1 day.

Comment: how to extend expire time??

Comment: Change the line `date.setTime(date.getTime()+(1*24*60*60*1000))` to something like `date.setTime(date.getTime()+(1000*24*60*60*1000))`.